# How to run VBS in C

Tags: c, vbscript

Does anyone know how I can run a VBS code in a C code?

I don't say run an external file, I say run a vbs CODE in the same code as C

In the same way Javascript and HTML come together, I want to do it with C and VBS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Responding to comments**

1. There are two ways to add macro support to your applications. Pay **money** to Microsoft and license VBA or use VBScript/JScript for free.
2. C requires a lot of plumbing code. EG a `.` in C++/VB6 is lines of code in C as it has no knowledge of COM. But to write C one has to choose to use C++ or C# and restrict oneself from using the inbuilt features and then duplicate the same features with lots of lines of code. There is plenty of 20 year old source code on the internet showing how.

VBScript is an Active Scripting language. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting. This allows COM programming languages to add VBS/JS macros to their programs.

Active Scripting allows you to add a macro language to your program.

You can of course implement IActiveScripting and there is plenty of C code for that on the internet.

For 32 bit programs only there is a MSScript.ocx control that implements IActiveScript and related interfaces in an easy control.

The VBScript code is (I'm not a C programmer - but in C# and C++ [but not C] it is just as easy as VBScript) as they both do COM easily.

```
set ScriptControl1 = wscript.createObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl",SC)
    With ScriptControl1
        .Language = "VBScript"
        .UseSafeSubset = False
        .AllowUI = True
        .AddCode Script
End With
```

The documentation was in System32 as msscript.chm but is no longer present in Win 10.

Here is some C# sample code. **Note** 32 Bit ONLY. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/libraries/call-script-control-run-method

Comment: You're answer isn't complete, but is correct. I don't understand why is so outrageous to ask how to run some VB script programmatically...

Comment: @Frankie_C Because there is nothing that can be done in VBScript that can’t be done natively in C. Would need to expand on their use case to understand why they even need to to do it. This answer doesn’t even mention C it talks about COM and usage in C# not sure how any of that is relevant. But without more information from the OP, who can know…or even give an accurate answer.

Comment: @user692942 I understand your point. I just intended the question as "how to run VBScripts" programmatically from C. But reading again the question the OP asks how run VBS **not in external file**, but inside C, that isn't very clear (put VBS in a static buffer and pass it to the interpreter?), and not, maybe, very useful.